# Show 300x250 ads in screens that can fit them

Tags: android, xml, layout

My Android app shows an ad at the bottom. I want to show 300x250 ad for large screens where the ad will fit, and a regular 320x50 banner for smaller screens.

Do I set the ad height in values-large, values-xlarge or values-hdpi, values-xhdpi?

I will put a dimens.xml file in these folders and set the height to 250dp or 50dp there.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using for your ads?

Comment: im using mopub mopub.com

Answer (score 0):

i used values-large, values-xlarge to set larger ad height for larger screens.